# PHP Parsing From Right

Tags: php, string-parsing

I have a string like **$filename** = "**stack.over.flow.zip**" and I want to parse it and **take** just "**zip**" **part** from the string. I spend 3 hours on php.net. However, I couldn't found any method. By the way, there is not just a string, there are lots of variables.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the PHP instruction manual instead of w3schools? That is what I do. You might find something like this useful: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: `echo pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a = explode('.', $filename );
echo end($a);
```

Functions used:

- [end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)
- [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

**Alternative:**

```
$last_three_chars = substr( $filename, -3 );
echo $last_three_chars ;
```

[substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: Thank you, it is a solution that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$pathinfo = pathinfo('stack.over.flow.zip');
echo 'Extension: '.$pathinfo['extension'];

will produce:
Extension: zip
```

Function used:
[Pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)